# display values from a for-loop in a table-like order to make it more clear and clean?

Tags: c++, for-loop

info: the majority of my problem is solved so far. please scroll to the very bottom to "**here is my progress so far**" to help me further, if you want to. thanks!

i have the following code and i would like to display the compiled results of this code in a clean table-like order to make it more clear for the users looking at the compiled command line program.

> ```
> #include <iostream>
> #include <cmath>
> using namespace std;
>
> int main()
> {double x;
> for(x=-10;x<=10;x+=0.5)
>     cout << "x=" << x << 3*x*x-7*x+5 << endl;
>     return 0;
> }
> ```

i was a little bit in a hurry so i couldnt really see what the teacher wrote on the board how to add a table-like ordering to it.  i only remember something like this:

> ```
> #include <iostream>
> #include <cmath>
> using namespace std;
>
> int main()
> {double x;
> for(x=-10;x<=10;x+=0.5)
>     cout << "x=" << x << "|*|" << 3*x*x-7*x+5 << endl;
>     return 0;
> }
> ```

i know the 2nd code is probably totally wrong, but it was a code with this symbol: |

does that make any sense for someone? maybe someone can figure out what exactly my teacher tried. or maybe there is another way to display the values in a good and clear order.

let me give you an example what i exactly mean by clear order.
the following example will show you compiled results (in cmd) of the first code (chaotic, no order etc)

> ```
> x=-10 375 
> x=-9.5 465 
> x=-9 123 
> x=-8.5 124
> ```

instead of the result above, i would like to have something like..

> ```
> x=  -  10.0     375 
> x=  -   9.5     465 
> x=  -   9       123 
> x=  -   8.5     124
> ```

unfortunately i dont know how to do that. i looked up some methods, but i was thinking: maybe what my teacher tried to show is easier than the methods i looked up. so maybe someone here knows how it is done the way i tried to do in the 2nd code. if not, i would be glad if someone could tell me the shortest and easiest way to sort the output.

thanks in advance

.---------------------------------- .

**here is my progress so far**. i used setw to add width to the lines. the changed code would look like this (with include iomanip added):

> `cout << std::setw(10) << x << std::setw(10) << 3*x*x-7*x+5 << endl;`

problem is, the number ranges dont fit. like.. the single digits, ten-step digits, hundred-step digit are not in the same row. they kind of look like this:

```
      -10.0         375  
      -9.5       342.25
```

etc..

i would like the make the result into something like this, you can clearly see the first digit, 2nd digit etc... of the numbers:

```
      - 10.0         375  
      -  9.5         342.25
```

someone maybe knows how i give the command to order it like that?

Comment: Take a look at [std::setw](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setw)

Comment: @TedLyngmo thanks, thats what i was looking for! just a last question. now I made this: 

`cout << std::setw(10) << x << std::setw(10) << 3*x*x-7*x+5 << endl;`

how exactly can i tell the code, that it should order single, tenth, hundreds numbers below the same line? as displayed in the 2nd output in the original post. (sorry formatting is a bit hard in a comment. i will edit the original post to show my progress)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You combine `std::setw` with `std::setprecision` and `std::fixed`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main() {
    std::cout << std::setprecision(2) << std::fixed;
    for(double x = -10.0; x <= 10.; x += 0.5) {
        std::cout << std::setw(10) << x << std::setw(10) << 3 * x * x - 7 * x + 5 << "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, thats awesome, it worked. now i jsut try to understand what each command you just told me is doing. so let me tell you my guess: setprecision tells you how many number it shall display after a comma (like if there is the number= 45.6789 and prescision is set to 2, then it will only show you 45,67) what i dont quite understand is, why it shows 6 digits after the comma when i just delete the part "std::setprecision(2)". and the std::fixed probably makes them in a nice row. well and to be honest i didnt really get why i need to add "std::"

Comment: Yes, you can use [std::setprecision](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setprecision) to change from the default 6 digits to something else. [std::fixed](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/fixed) is used to set a fixed number of digits, so that `0.1` becomes `0.10` (with precision 2). For the last question: [Why is “using namespace std” considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Comment: thanks for that link. that makes it more clear. but when do i need to use " std::" now? for every single command i use? like.. std::for ? std::if ? std::case? etc etc? or whre exactly should std:: be used to prevent future conflict by possible updates. i mean right now i am only using one namespace, thats namespace std. in this case its not needed to use std::cout etc.? so only using the namespace tags in code when you use multiple libraries?

Comment: No, you don't need `std::` for any of the [keywords](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword) and if you use `std::cout` and `std::cin` a lot, you can bring those in with `using std::cout, std::cin;` and skip `std::` for those in your code. It's a matter of taste I suppose, but I prefer having the `std::` there to make it clear that it's a `std` function/object/lib.